# C# OfType() -clarification

Tags: c#

Do we use OfType() for filtering purpose ?

Say example,

if i use

```
object[] numbers = { null, 1.0, "two", 3, 4.30, 5, "six", 7.0 };
var doubles = numbers.OfType<double>();
```

It just filters double values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's both a filter (on the elements) and a "cast" (on the collection, not the elements). In other words, it filters the elements down to only those of the specified type, and returns an enumerable of the specified type.